# Rendering images in a rails app deployed on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, deployment

My app has an `image_tag` that displays a picture based on the current `@player`. Player has a field `image_name` that is set to `"#{player.first_name}_#{player.last_name}"`, and I get the image's source based on the `@player.image_name` field. This works perfectly when viewing it locally, however, when deployed to Heroku it only works the first time. What I mean by that, is that when my page loads, it renders `home.html.erb` and the picture displays, however, after a `.click` event, an ajax call changes the value of `@player` and updates the html using jQuery.

This is where the issue arises. When I first load the page on Heroku and inspect the image element, the source looks like this:

```
src="/assets/Adrian_Peterson-94b1c3dd9514a0c926efbdf4e5193329.jpg"
```

However, the `@player.full_name` field is actually `=> Adrian_Peterson` (without the code after it). Where is that sequence of numbers/letters coming from? Why does my code know the location of this picture the first time it is loaded, but when the jQuery injects the new image code, which comes up like this:

```
src="/images/Frank_Gore.jpg"
```

the picture does not display?

So my questions are:

- Where does the code at the end of the picture's source come from?
- How can I reference the picture based on the `@player.image_name` field if I don't know what this code will be when it is deployed to Heroku?

**EDIT:**

This is added to the home page (part of a larger block of html) in the ajax success callback. `data.player1` is a Player object.

`/home.js.coffee/`

```
< img src="/assets/' + data.player1.first_name + '_' + data.player1.last_name + '.jpg" alt="' + data.player1.first_name + '_' + data.player1.last_name + '" class= "playerpic" >' +`
```

This is the way the image is referenced before an ajax call, from `/home.html.erb`.

```
<%= image_tag("#{@player1.first_name}_#{@player1.last_name}.jpg", alt: "#{@player1.first_name}_#{@player1.last_name}", class: "playerpic") %>
```

Comment: Try src="/assets/Frank_Gore.jpg" instead of src="/images/Frank_Gore.jpg"

Comment: Are you using paperclip gem to upload images?

Comment: @NikitaSingh, no, I am just saving the images to the /images/ folder. Users will never need to upload an image.

Comment: @Neeraj, I made change that you suggested, but it did not change the outcome at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: When request goes to ajax it might be returning json. With that data we are not able to display image. But the normal page load automatically knows image url. So, in ajax generate HTML and with jQuery put that at right place. You may use the same code as used in normal page (without ajax). Hope it must work if done correctly.

Comment: @Neeraj, I've added the way the image tag is called above, both when the page is initially loaded (from home.html.erb) and after the ajax call (from home.js.coffee). I've tried using ERB in home.js.coffee, but I've gotten errors. Will it work if I use ERB instead of data.player1.first_name? If so, what should the coffeescript look like that includes the ERB? Thanks again!